# In WidgetKit, how do I set a default intent value from dynamic options obtained via a network call?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, widgetkit, siri-intent

When a user first installs my widget, when they select "Edit Widget", I'd like a default choice to show up instead of "Choose." This is a dynamic intent and the options are retrieved from a network call.

In my IntentHandler, there are two functions I am playing with:

```
extension IntentHandler: MyIntentHandling {
    func provideMyValueOptionsCollection(for intent: MyIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<MyValue>?, Error?) -> Void) { }

    func defaultMyValue(for intent: MyIntent) -> [MyValue]? { }
}
```

I can get the options via a network call for `provideMyValueOptionsCollection` by calling the completion handler once the values have been retrieved. But `defaultMyValue` is synchronous, so it won't accept a closure return value from a network call (get error: `Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '[MyValue]'`). Is there a way to provide a default value obtained from a network call to the Edit Widget screen?

Comment: what if you return nil, and then once you fetch the data return the real data from the network call?

Comment: I ended up storing the response data in a cache and lodaing that in the `defaultMyValue function`. Unfortunately that means no defaults the first time the widget is loaded, but defaults are eventually provided from a cache once the widget relaunches.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and like you ended up solving it by storing the data in `UserDefaults` and also had the same problem of not displaying the data when it was first shown

I solved this problem with the following solution:

**Remove the time-consuming operation in the `defaultMyValue` method**

We had the operation of converting images to binary data (*image url string -> `URL` -> `Data`*), which was perfectly solved when we moved this operation from the `defaultMyValue` method to somewhere else (e.g. in the UI).